# Conditional count column

Tags: sql, count

I have a table called `tbl_data` and am currently doing a query like this:

SELECT
tbl_data.id,
tbl_data.name
FROM
table_name AS tbl_data

This returns something like this

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| abc | name1 |
| abc | name2 |
| def | name3 |

I want to be able to count the number of times ID is in the table like this:

| Count of ID | ID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | abc | name1 |
| 2 | abc | name2 |
| 1 | def | name3 |

I thought I could do something like this:

```
SELECT
count(id),
```

which only ever returns 1. so instead I have tried

```
SELECT
(SELECT(COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE id = tbl_data.id))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY tbl_data.id) as count_of_id,
       tbl_data.id, tbl_data.name
FROM table_name AS tbl_data
```